# Panel estimation with Stata - how to do by data subsets

Tags: stata

I need to run regressions on both OLS and fixed effects panel models. The dependent variable is arranged by a group variable. The OLS proceeds like this:

```
sysuse data, clear
bysort group: reg depVar expVar1 expVar2
```

That works as it should. However, I have not managed to make this work with panel data:

```
sysuse data, clear
xtset id year
bysort group: xtreg depVar expVar1 expVar2, fe
```

However, an error terminates the process after defining the panel variables because there are duplicate observations. That is not a "real" error because after sorting by group there would be no duplicates.

I know that I could reshape the data to wide format and type a separate line for each estimation, but I am wondering whether there are other, more convenient ways around this.

Answer (score 2):

In principle it works (see code below):

```
webuse airacc, clear
xtset airline time, delta(1)
xtreg relsize pmi ait, fe
gen indicator = round(runiform())
bys indic: xtreg relsize pmi ait, fe
```

The problem seems to be the dublicates. I never came across such a problem. However, you could run two separate regressions: i) preserve the data, ii) drop observations from group x iii) run the regression iv) restore the data and go to step i). This should yield identical results as long as groups are mutually exclusive.

```
webuse airacc, clear
xtset airline time, delta(1)
xtreg relsize pmi ait, fe
gen indicator = round(runiform())

preserve
drop if indic == 1
xtreg relsize pmi ait, fe
restore

preserve
drop if indic == 0 
xtreg relsize pmi ait, fe
restore

bys indic: xtreg relsize pmi ait, fe
```

Comment: Peter: Sorry for my poor example and thank you for providing a better! However, that's not exactly what I was after. In my data each id year pair appears once for each group element, i.e. separate tables bind together by rows. You create a new grouping variable to a non-stacked table, which does not create any duplicates. Perhaps I need to think again using `reshape`.

Comment: You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using `dataex`.

Comment: Antti: it is a bit hard for me to understand the structure of your data. However, I think reshaping the data will help...